# How do i unbrick my lg sunshine

Tags: recovery-mode, troubleshooting

I had app hangovers restarting over and over again and could not open my settings on my phone app or any other application so I open the back of the phone and turned it off by pulling the battery out and when I put the battery back in its stuck on the lg logo screen and wont do anything else

Answer (score 0):

I read the following procedure should work.

### [LG Shine II](http://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-hard-reset-and-delete-all-settings-with-button-combo.247619/)

> - Power off the phone completely.
> - Press and hold (in this order) Volume Up+Volume Down+Home+Power, until you see the Android character and a box-unloading animation.

### [LG Sunrise L15G](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/lg/lg-l15g/)

> - Power off the phone completely
> - press and hold the Volume Down and Power button together for a couple of seconds.
> - When the LG logo is displayed, let go of the Power key, keep pressing the Volume Down and then press once more the Power button.
> - You should release all buttons when the Factory Mode appears on the screen.
> - Confirm process by choosing appropriate options using Volume rockers to navigate and Power button to confirm.

---

You might lose any contacts, messages, photos etc that you have not already backed up.